# XSLT Processor transformToXML no style information

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am trying to use the XstlProcessor Class in PHP (version 5.5.19) to perform a xls-transformation. If I execute the script and the result gets printed, only the old xml file with no transformation is printed and it says "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.".

Part of the script which should perform the transformation:

```
$xml = new DomDocument;
$xml->load("tmp.xml");
$xsl = new DomDocument;
$xsl->load("bookings.xsl");

$proc = new XsltProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$html = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
if(!$html) die('XLST processing error\n');
echo $html;
```

The XSL-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Booking Overview</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Model</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="bookings/booking">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@bdate" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="customer/name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="customer/surname"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="address/street"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="address/city"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="address/country"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="vehicle/brand"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="vehicle/model"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- all bookings-->
<bookings>
<!--booking-->
<booking bdate ="2015-01-14">
    <customer>
        <name>Josef</name>
        <surname>Mongo</surname>
    </customer>
    <address>
        <street>Alberstrasse</street>
        <city>Graz</city>
        <country>Austria</country>
    </address>
    <vehicle>
        <brand>Audi</brand>
        <model>R8</model>
    </vehicle>
</booking>
<!--booking-->
<booking bdate ="2014-07-23">
    <customer>
        <name>Hannelore</name>
        <surname>Metutschnik</surname>
    </customer>
    <address>
        <street>Moserhofgasse</street>
        <city>Graz</city>
        <country>Austria</country>
    </address>
    <vehicle>
        <brand>Fiat</brand>
        <model>Punto</model>
    </vehicle>
</booking>
<!--booking-->
<booking bdate ="2014-11-20">
    <customer>
        <name>Josef</name>
        <surname>Mongo</surname>
    </customer>
    <address>
        <street>Alberstrasse</street>
        <city>Graz</city>
        <country>Austria</country>
    </address>
    <vehicle>
        <brand>BMW</brand>
        <model>M6</model>
    </vehicle>
</booking>
<!--booking-->
<booking bdate ="2014-11-23">
    <customer>
        <name>Onder</name>
        <surname>Graf</surname>
    </customer>
    <address>
        <street>Mariahilferstrasse</street>
        <city>Wien</city>
        <country>Austria</country>
    </address>
    <vehicle>
        <brand>BMW</brand>
        <model>M6</model>
    </vehicle>
</booking>
<!--booking-->
<booking bdate ="2014-11-23">
    <customer>
        <name>Onder</name>
        <surname>Graf</surname>
    </customer>
    <address>
        <street>Mariahilferstrasse</street>
        <city>Wien</city>
        <country>Austria</country>
    </address>
    <vehicle>
        <brand>BMW</brand>
        <model>M6</model>
    </vehicle>
</booking>
</bookings>
```

Comment: Works for me, PHP 5.4.30 - I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: me neither, using php 5.6.3/win32. The output is `<htmL><body>.....`, not the "raw" xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input XML is well-formed and the XSLT code is correct. I cannot reproduce your problem under PHP 5.4.30.

I suspect you are saving the result in a file with an `*.xml` extension instead of `*.html`. If opened with a browser, it will report that no stylesheet is associated with this XML file. So, the solution is: change the file extension.